# Accessibility NVDA Screen reader issue - Switching between anchor tag reading both the label

Tags: angular, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

Accessibility NVDA Screen reader issue - Switching between anchor tag reading both the label

```
        <div class="my-toggle-bar">
          <a *ngIf="mode == 'inbox' && scope == 'Knowledge'" aria-label="Knowledge filter button active" href="javascript:void(0)"
             (click)="changeScope('Knowledge')"
             [ngClass]="{'active': scope == 'Knowledge'}"
             class="active">                 
             <span>Knowledge</span>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="mode == 'inbox' && scope == 'Support'" aria-label="Knowledge filter button" href="javascript:void(0)"
             (click)="changeScope('Knowledge')"
             [ngClass]="{'active': scope == 'Knowledge'}"
             class="active">                 
             <span>Knowledge</span>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="mode == 'inbox' && scope == 'Knowledge'" aria-label="Support filter button" href="javascript:void(0)"
             [ngClass]="{'active': scope == 'Support'}"
             (click)="changeScope('Support')">
             <span>Support</span>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="mode == 'inbox' && scope == 'Support'" aria-label="Support filter button active" href="javascript:void(0)"
            [ngClass]="{'active': scope == 'Support'}"
            (click)="changeScope('Support')">
            <span>Support</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

[Toggle button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmb5t.png)

I have to use NVDA for accessibility screen reader. When I toggle between the anchor tag, it reads both label as "Knoweledge support". Lets' say Knowledge is active and I am switching to Support or the reverse way. It should only read one. Normally when I am pressing tab or shift+tab, it is reading as expected.

- I tried with different screen reader - chrome extension.
- Tried by adding TabIndex
- Tried using aria-labelledBy....etc

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your script is actually removing these anchor elements from the DOM? If so, that’s pretty bad for accessibility. You must not remove an element that has focus, or you have to set the focus elsewhere before removing it. [Links are for navigation between pages](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#link), they should not toggle between states. You should use radio buttons for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way of going about toggle switches. The author here has implemented several ways of doing so accessibly, which looks similar to your design. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/09/building-inclusive-toggle-buttons/#auxiliary-labeling

Having some sort of `aria-checked`/`pressed`/`selected` state will help the screen reader identify the active state.

On another note, the `aria-label` should match the visible label (2.5.3: Label in Name). You can provide additional guidance with `aria-labelledby`.